# Итерация цифр в числе

Tags: c++

Нужно перемножить между собой цифры введенного числа. Но не могу перевести числа из строчного типа в целочисленный. В строке `result *= stoi(number[i]);` `stoi` подчеркнуто красным.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "string"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int result = 1;
    string number;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++)
    {
        result *= stoi(number[i]);
    }
    cout << result;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Разумеется, не работает. Что хочет аргументом `stoi`? Строку. А вы что передаёте? Символ.

Answer (score 3):

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> s;

    long long int result = 1;

    for ( char c : s ) result *= c - '0';

    std::cout << "The product of the digits is " << result << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль может выглядеть как

```
Enter a number: 123456789987654321
The product of the digits is 131681894400
```

Если ваш компилятор не поддерживает цикл на основе диапазонов то вы можете написать

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ ) result *= s[i] - '0';
```

Answer (score -1):

В итоге решил сам таким способом:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "string"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int result = 1;
    string number;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++)
    {
        switch (number[i])
        {
        case '1':
            result *= 1;
            break;
        case '2':
            result *= 2;
            break;
        case '3':
            result *= 3;
            break;
        case '4':
            result *= 4;
            break;
        case '5':
            result *= 5;
            break;
        case '6':
            result *= 6;
            break;
        case '7':
            result *= 7;
            break;
        case '8':
            result *= 8;
        case '9':
            result *= 9;
            break;
        case '0':
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << result;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Ужос. Таблица или number[i] - 0x30 куда как проще...

Comment: Прост! Прост как правда.

Comment: @vdublevsky Прежде, чем подводить итоги, посмотрите мое решение.:)

Comment: `case '0': break;` неверно. У вас в этом случае должен получиться честный 0 в ответе.